# how to alias each column in table where column names store as array

Tags: sql

My column names are stored in n array like below, where the column names are dynamic:

`$column1='name,address,contact';`

I want to alias each element of the array like `c.name`, `c.address`, `c.contact`.
Is it possible?

Comment: Dynamic SQL is the way to go.

Comment: @jarlh Is dynamic SQL available in "all" or most RDBMS?

Comment: @RaduGheorghiu, IFAIK it is in most. At least in ANSI SQL, which is assumed when the only tag is <sql>.